# how to make a collection view to scroll horizontally having infinite scroll in both directions left, as well as right in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I want a horizontal scrollable collection view  to scroll in both side(left and right), now it has continuous scrolling only in right direction, how to implement in left side ?

```
let itemcount = array?.count ?? 0
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
                if scrollView == DemoCollectionView {
                    let offSet = scrollView.contentOffset.x
                    let width = scrollView.frame.width
                    let horizontalCenter = width / 2
                    let currentPage = Int(offSet + horizontalCenter) / Int(width)
                    if currentPage >= itemCount / 2 {
                        itemCount += array?.count ?? 0
                        DemoCollectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using "scrollToItemAtIndexPath" method. Swipe direction you can get from scrollview delegate methods.

**Scroll right to left**

```
collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: dataArray.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Right, animated: false)
```

**Scroll left to right**

```
collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .left, animated: false)
```

You can also apply a transformation on collection view to get similar.

Comment: thank you so much, can you please provide me an example for this

Comment: Anybody who can help me out on this please, Thanks in advance